# GET response after POST

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are using a 3rd party API to validate the existence of our customer's emails when they are registering.

This email validation service has two steps:

First I need to `POST` a `JSON` with a list of emails to the API and to receive a uniqueID.

In the second step, I need to send the uniqueID to the API (concating it to the URL) and to receive a list of the valid emails.

The problem is that I am not getting the right response from the second step - it's the same response as the first one

- when I am executing step 2 separately from step 1 I am getting the right data.
- I am getting the right data if I am, adding `alert(1)` before the second call but with `SetTimeout` it does not work.

**My Code:**

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="sendEmails()"> sendEmails</a><br>
```

```
function sendEmails() {
    var data =  '{"entries":[{"inputData":"email2@gmail.com"},{"inputData":"email1@gmail.com"}]}'
    var settings = {
        "url": _apiUrl,
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(_authString),
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
        },
        "processData": false,
        "data": data
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (res) {
        validateEmailsByUniqueId(res.uniqueID)
    });

}

function validateEmailsByUniqueId (uniqueId){
    var settings = {
        "url": _apiUrl + uniqueId,
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(_authString),
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            }
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    });    
}
```

Comment: can you post the code for the call to sendEmails too?

Comment: Without the API, my first question is does each call have a different endpoint URL or are they the exact same just with different data passed?

Comment: It's the same URL but with the uniqueID concatenated to the URL

Comment: There are several ways to debug your problem. The code, by itself, doesn't really hold any strange fact. I would suggest you to: 1) Check whether `uniqueId` is valid. For such a task, just log it. 2) Inspect your browser's network tab. Looking at it, you should be able to track the **request** sent from your client and detect where the error might be. There is no reason for the requests to be the same. Is the code **exactly** the one you posted?

Comment: Unfortunately as long as we don't know what 3rd party API you are using, and as long as we can't see it's docs or code, it's not possible to answer your question.